# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Byte is not a valid external type for schema of bigint

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have an rdd of columns (id,name) whose datatypes are (byte, string). When I am trying to convert it to a dataframe using below schema

```
id - longtype
name - stringtype
```

I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Byte is not a valid external type for schema of bigint
```

Why is the byte not getting converted to long. Byte range is -128 to 127 which is within the range of long. I am able to convert short/integer to long, but not byte

Any reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your approach is here but guessing that its `RDD -> DataFrame` using a defined schema.

To create a dataframe using a predefined schema, we will convert RDDs to an RDD of type `Row`. And since there is no automatic conversion of type in this case, we should explicitly cast it to Long while creating `RDD[Row]`. In the end the code should look like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, LongType,  StructField, StructType} 

val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((192.toByte, "abc"),(168.toByte, "def")))
val schema = new StructType()
.add(StructField("id", LongType, true))
.add(StructField("name", StringType, true))

val rowRDD:RDD[Row] = data.map(row => Row(row._1.toLong, row._2))
val dfWithSchema = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)

dfWithSchema.show
+---+----+                                                                      
| id|name|
+---+----+
|-64| abc|
|-88| def|
+---+----+
```